# Does deep linking my app with social media still work on iOS?

Tags: ios, deep-linking, social-media

I am trying to make my app open whenever I open a shared link of the website on social media, especially Facebook. However, it's not working.
I actually tried opening common websites like a youtube. link shared on FB using my iPhone, however, it always opens in the FB browser!
Isn't there an option to cancel in-app browser on FB on iPhone like there was on android? Is there a new policy against such a thing I am not aware of?
Same goes for Twitter

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to cancel in-app browser in fb in iOS and deep linking for your application still works from any social media platform.
Below is a great reference to understand how the deep linking works in iOS.

https://medium.com/@stasost/ios-how-to-open-deep-links-notifications-and-shortcuts-253fb38e1696

Hope this would be some help for you.